# Sprite disappearing to the back of another sprite on moving to defined point via transform.position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a difficulty with Unity2D's Sprite rendering.

Currently I have a sprite for a gameBoard, an empty GameObject holding the spawnPoint, a random sprite marking it, as well as a playerSprite to be instantiated as a prefab. If I am just using the hierarchy on Unity, the playerSprite shows perfectly above the gameBoard, and "hard-coding" its position will always keep it above the gameBoard sprite, visible to the eye.

The problem comes when I want to instantiate the gameBoard and dynamically adding the playerPrefabs into the game.

Here is the current code snippet I am currently using:

```
gameBoard.SetActive(true); //gameBoard is defined as a public gameObject with its element defined in Unity as the gameBoard sprite. 
Player.playerSprite = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("playerSprite"));
Player.playerSprite.transform.localPosition = spawnPoint.transform.localPosition;
```

The result is that the spritePrefab spawns at the place I want perfectly, but behind the gameBoard sprite, making it hidden when the game runs.

The result is the same when using transform.position instead of transform.localPosition

How should I code the transform part. such that I can still make my playerSprite visible? Thanks.

Comment: Please be sure to use the Unity3d tag; the Unity tag is for the Unity dependency injection framework.

Comment: noted. 

Additional Information: None of the sprites included any other components other than the sprites itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely not an issue with the position, but rather the [Sorting Order](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.html) of your Sprite Renderers.

The default values for any SpriteRenderer is Layer = Default & Sorting Order = 0

Sprite Renderers with a higher sorting order are rendered on top of those with a lower value.

Add the following lines to the end of your code, and try it out.

```
gameBoard.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
Player.playerSprite.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
```

Obviously, you could do the same thing in the inspector as well.

Comment: I have managed to get this to work! While the gameBoard's sortingOrder code isn't necessary, I realised that the playerSprite's sortingOrder is at -1. Dynamically setting the sprite to 1 did the trick.